# form_tag onComplete event not work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to call a javascript function when click the submit button.I used form_tag , but the function did not get triggered.I want something like the following:

```
<%= form_tag show_table_job_plate_path, :onSubmit => 'start_form_request(); ' ,:onComplete  => 'end_form_request();' ,:update => { :success => 'well_table_section' },:remote => true, method: :GET  do %>
```

on submit is working but on complete is not working  please help me?

Comment: There is no `onComplete` option as far as i remember. You should attach a `ajax:success` event on the form.

Comment: i tried for that also but still it is not working could you please give the how to add ajax:success

Comment: i am new to rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using form_tag with remote:true, which means your rails server is going to send you response in JS format. So you can call your function with following two ways:

1) respond_to block: simplest and easy solution.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :js => "end_form_request();" }
end
```

2) js.erb file:

for your controller action you can have "action_name.js.erb" file, and in that file you can call you js function 'end_form_request()' directly.

Hope it helps you.

**Updated:**

**action.js.erb**

```
$("#well_table_section").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'well_table', :locals => { :params => @params } ) %>");
end_form_request("<%= @params %>");
```

Comment: hi its working thanks but it is not taking the values of the for please tell me when i have to give the function

Comment: $("#well_table_section").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'well_table', :locals => { :params => @params } ) %>");  this is my action.js.erb here if i call js params value is not passing

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you are asking, what I understood is "You want to pass form values to that function"...right ???. If so please check the updated answer.

Comment: @BangaruNarayana, If the updated answer solves your problem please accept the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `onComplete` event on HTML Form. [Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

[image]

If you want to trigger something after on Ajax Call Complete. Use Ajax events like success, complete, error.

```
$("#yourform").bind('ajax:complete', function(data, status, xhr) {
   //Your On Complete Code
});
```

[Check this](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) for all rails ajax events.

Comment: could you please change this rails 2.3.2 code to rails 4.2 <% form_remote_tag(:url => { :action => 'show_table' }, :method => :GET, :update => { :success => 'well_table_section' }, :loading => 'start_form_request()', :complete => 'end_form_request()' ) do -%>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$("#your_form_id").on("ajax:success", function(xhr,data){
    ... //your complete function here.
})
```

Comment: i tried it but still it is not working on Submit after i want whent complete the form the js function should call

Comment: What do u mean by when complete the form?

Comment: <%= submit_tag "Enable", {:id => 'enable_button'}    %>
      
      <%= submit_tag "Disable", {:disabled => true, :id => 'disable_button'} %>

Comment: <%= submit_tag "Enable", {:id => 'enable_button'}    %>
      
      <%= submit_tag "Disable", {:disabled => true, :id => 'disable_button'} %>     i am using this tags inside the form when i click on enable it should be go to disable mode and do some function for that i wrritten some form loading and complete

Comment: could you please change this rails 2.3.2 code to rails 4.2 <% form_remote_tag(:url => { :action => 'show_table' }, :method => :GET, :update => { :success => 'well_table_section' }, :loading => 'start_form_request()', :complete => 'end_form_request()' ) do -%>

Answer (score 0):

As per your request I converted your requirement into Rails 4

This is form tag

```
<%= form_tag show_table_job_plate_path, remote: true, html: { onSubmit: 'start_form_request();', id: 'yourForm' }  do %>
```

When you added the `show_table_job_plate_path` in the form you don't need to `method: :GET`

After the form you have to add this script.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourForm').on('ajax:complete', function(e, data, status, xhr){
        // Write onComplete Code
      end_form_request();

    }).on('ajax:success',function(e, xhr, status, error){

        // Write onSuccess Code
      well_table_section();

    }).on('ajax:error',function(e, xhr, status, error){
      // Write onError Code


    });
  });
</script>
```